# Laravel getting error 'Trying to access array offset on value of type int' While call aritsan command Artisan::call('cache:clear');

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to clear a cache using code. It throws me an error `Trying to access array offset on value of type int`

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return "Cache is cleared";
});
```

Error in the line `elseif ('-' === $key[0])`

```
protected function parse()
{
    foreach ($this->parameters as $key => $value) {
        if ('--' === $key) {
            return;
        }
        if (0 === strpos($key, '--')) {
            $this->addLongOption(substr($key, 2), $value);
        } elseif ('-' === $key[0]) {
            $this->addShortOption(substr($key, 1), $value);
        } else {
            $this->addArgument($key, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $key[0] what are you getting in this?

Comment: I dont know I haven't printed anything at that line

Comment: Which PHP version you're using?

Comment: php 7 version I am using

Comment: ran composer update command

Answer (score 0):

Key variable might not be array now. You can explicitly typecast this to array

```
protected function parse()
{
    foreach ($this->parameters as $key => $value) {
        $key = (array)$key;
        if ('--' === $key) {
            return;
        }
        if (0 === strpos($key, '--')) {
            $this->addLongOption(substr($key, 2), $value);
        } elseif ('-' === $key[0]) {
            $this->addShortOption(substr($key, 1), $value);
        } else {
            $this->addArgument($key, $value);
        }
    }
}
```